# Implementing Hot Reload feature in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, hot-reload

The people who are familiar with React and Flutter would easily understand this.

But for others, here's the explanation:

- When ever I change something in my python file which contains tkinter code, the change should be reflected in the main window (*the main window should not re-open to reflect the changes*).

I have tried to search on web as well as on stack over flow, but all the results are for updating value in entry, label, buttons etc. But what I want is, the whole window should be updated when ever I change something in my main file, and the main window should not be reopened to do so. So in short, **updating whole window without closing it, on every changes in the main file or automatically reload your program on save without reopening!**

What have I tried?:

- I tried to detect change in file using `os.getsize` which satisfied the first part of my question, but however I am not able to solve the second part i.e window should not be closed.

```
import os
main__tkinter_filename="myfile.py"
initial_filesize=os.path.getsize(main_tkinter_filename) # Getting size of the file for
                                                        # comparison.
while 1:
    final_filesize=os.path.getsize(main_tkinter_filename)
    if final_filsize<intial_filesize or final_filesize>initial_filesize:
        webbrowser.open(main_tkinter_filename)
```

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.mainloop
```

results in the below GUI:
[image: Tkinter Basic GUI]

If i have added `a=Label(text='text')`and`a.pack()` after `root=Tk()`, it should show me the label, and if i have removed the same code, it should remove them.

Comment: the library would have had to implement this feature, as far as I know, they haven't, so this is not very practical to achieve, not impossible and I can think of a few solutions but all of them would require a lot of work, the easiest one I can think of would constantly open and close the window which you might as well do manually and only when you need

Comment: @Matiiss , thanks for your response, it would be helpful you can draft am answer providing atleast the logic or some sort of hint on how to achive the solution.

Comment: The solution to this would be very complicated. There's a difference between a web page and an actual running Python script. There's no way to change the execution of one version of a script into the execution of another version of the script without restarting the whole program. Maybe, at least, you could import most of your classes and what-not from another file, and then re-import it when the file is edited? Again, that would be extremely difficult. You'd probably be better off making a website.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin , But an webpage is also written in a file, and live server just reloads the page.

Comment: A web page is a _page_; that is, it's a set of instructions for how things should look and act on events. It's not "running" in the sense that a Python script is; besides, reloading a page is basically doing the equivalent of restarting a Python program: the browser stops showing the current HTML and stops all current JavaScript and what-not that's running, then re-requests the whole HTML page, and starts all the JavaScript running again.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Can you explain what kind of changes do you intend to make in those files?

Comment: @Thingamabobs , I just want to refect changes done in my python(tkinter) file like if i add a=Label(root,text='hello').pack() in my file, it should add it the GUI without reopening the file. I hope i have cleared it :)

Comment: @SylvesterKruin , yes you are correct, but is there any way to just refect the the changes in the file?

Comment: You would need to build a whole framework for this. [SO] isnt designed to answer these types of questions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"the whole window should be updated"_? Is it ok if all of the data entered in the UI is reset to their default values?

Comment: @BryanOakley , I have editted my question, hope it clarified, and i dont want to reset the UI to default value, i just want to refect changes made in the last frame of tkinter.

Comment: HTML is a Markup Language, not a Language more a Format, and can be rendered again on modification. A Python script is compiled and needs to be started again if you modify it. Running a program is not rendering the program.

Comment: The problem with your request is that we not only need to reflect the changes to the GUI, but also to the normal code itself. What you want is finally just a real-time python compiler, and that is already kind of hard by itself, not even counting the part where you need to only update the parts of the code that changed. I have been working on it for I would say 10 hours and I am starting to realize that this is really a complicated and complex thing...

Comment: There you go, [here is the full code on GitHub](https://github.com/D-00-python/real-time-tkinter-gui). It is already 256 lines long, and I stopped at the point where I need to make the old and new lines correspond to remember which variable has been added with which line, to be able to know which variable to remove when you remove a certain line of code. I may continue this and eventually finish it, but I think I will not put that much effort into it as I don't believe it is worth the effort. Why do you really want your application not to refresh? This would be a lot easier.

Comment: With the code above on GitHub, I still have the problem that when you modify a line with a certain variable in it, deleting it is not enough, you also need to know every impact this line had, and this can range from `global foo` to redefining a variable to something else: the program needs to read the whole code again, and this has basically the same effect as refreshing your page. Maybe my solution can help once it's done properly, but only to a certain extend. If you want to go further than that, you will need to either make a new `tkinter`-like library, or rewrite the entire Python language

Comment: I don't think you still care (and I understand, I wouldn't either) but I just wanted to make sure the link to the GitHub repo was not broken. Here it is updated: https://github.com/d-002/real-time-tkinter-gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question by the best of my understanding,

I have some (a few projects of my own, still way too limited) experience with flutter which has hot-reload feature (**same as you described above**, which you want with python, mainly `tkinter`), I recently switched to python for gui (Loved it!), so I would like to share my research here:

I was successfully able to set up hot-reload both with kivy (kivymd hot reload, which comes with watchdog and kaki, which works **real-time**), and with tkinter, while there is a hitch with the later, you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> as to reload the `tkinter` window, but it works without having to re-run the python program, I will leave the link to the found resources here, hope it helps with your query!

To setup hot-reload with tkinter (requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), please refer [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580707).

To setup hot-reload with kivy/kivymd (real-time), which I personally prefer, you can find the official docs [here](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/kivymd/tools/hotreload/app/).

To mention, I use the above on Manjaro (Arch linux) with pycharm, atom, but I have also tried and have made it run successfully on Windows 10 with vs code (worked like charm)

Hope I could be of help! If you face any problem regarding the same, please feel free to ask! Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the solution it works perfect, but would it be possible to update just a particular frame?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I have finally found out a way to implement hot reload feature (*which @Stange answers provides*) but just updating the selected frame or code.

The basic idea is constanly reading the file and executing the selected code, and removing the object in a list which are meant to be removed.

```py
# Live Checker.py
import keyboard
while 1:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("Ctrl+r"):
        with open('test.py','r') as file:
            file_data=file.read()
            file_data_start_index=file_data.find("'@Start@'")
            file_data_end_index=file_data.find("'@End@'")
            exec_command=file_data[file_data_start_index:file_data_end_index]
            with open('exec_log.txt','w') as txt_file:
                txt_file.write(exec_command)
```

Here I am constantly checking if if `ctrl+r` key is pressed, and if pressed

- it reads the file,
- writes the selected code from the file into a txt file.
- I have specified the start and end of the code to be updated by `@Start@` and `@End@` respectively.

```py
# Main.py
def check():
    with open('exec_log.txt','r') as exec_c:
        exec_command=exec_c.read()

    if len(exec_command)==0:
        pass
    else:
        print(exec_command)
        exec('for i in root.winfo_children():i.destroy()\n'+exec_command)
        print('exec')
        with open('exec_log.txt','w') as exec_c:
            pass
        root.update()
    root.after(100,check)
root.after(100,check)
```

And in the main file, i have added the above code which continusly check if `exec_log.txt` file has any changes, and if changes are there, then it executes them and all so destroys the widget specified in the remove_list.

This is just a temporary solution which in my case helps me to implement the hot reload feature in tkinter.

Comment: As I understand, it only works with 1 GUI, and you need to name it `root`?

Comment: @D_00 , it executes the code in the selected region, so if you have multiple GUI under selected region you will notice changes in them too, and it's not necessary to name it root, you can change the name according to your wish.

Comment: Oh, I did not understand quite right. Also, do you need to manually type in "@start@" and "@end@" in the file? I haven't used `file.find()` before.

Comment: @D_00, Yes, `file.find()` isnt a function of file, its a function on string, it finds the index of the string given in it.

Comment: A nice thing would be to do this automatically, for example with the use of the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module, but then it tends to be complicated. I used it in [this code](https://github.com/D-00-python/real-time-tkinter-gui) on GitHub, you can check it out if you want, but it's not completely finished.

Comment: @D_00 , i tried your code, but was not able to run it. Even tried to fix it but i am not quite familiar with the difflib module

Comment: Me neither before coding this, and I'm still through the process of completing that code at a point where I don't think it's worth continuing. I don't remember if the code I provided even works, and anyway the whole purpose of it was just to show some ideas/starting points / show the OP how complicated the task ends up being, and that the best solution is just to refresh the entire code. I don't think your answer works when the user *removes* part of the code too. As I said in another comment, you need to take into account the user adding some code in a while loop already executed for example.

Comment: @D_00, by **removes part of code** you mean removing a complete line or a part of line?, for me my answer does work that's the reason i decided to post it as an answer here. You are right, the task is pretty complicated but as i have said this is just a temporary solution.

Comment: Say you have a line in your code like this: `foo = 'bar'`, followed by this line: `foo = 'baz'`. If you remove the second line, `foo` should be set back to `"bar"` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, right? I am sorry if I'm missing something but I couldn't quite work out how your code managed to achieve that.

Comment: @D_00 , It does that. The condition is that `Live Checker.py` should be running